# Python Asyncio blocked coroutine

Tags: python, asynchronous, zeromq, publish-subscribe, python-asyncio

I'm trying to code a simple program based on Asyncio and a Publish/Subscribe design pattern implemented with ZeroMQ. The publisher has 2 coroutines; one that listens for incoming subscriptions, and another one that  publishes the value (obtained via an HTTP request) to the subscriber. The subscriber subscribes to a specific parameter (the name of a city in this case), and waits for the value (the temperature in this city).

Here is my code:

**publisher.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import aiohttp
import aiozmq
import asyncio
import zmq


class Publisher:
    BIND_ADDRESS = 'tcp://*:10000'

    def __init__(self):
        self.stream = None
        self.parameter = ""

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def main(self):
        self.stream = yield from aiozmq.create_zmq_stream(zmq.XPUB, bind=Publisher.BIND_ADDRESS)
        tasks = [
            asyncio.async(self.subscriptions()),
            asyncio.async(self.publish())]
        print("before wait")
        yield from asyncio.wait(tasks)
        print("after wait")

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def subscriptions(self):
        print("Entered subscriptions coroutine")
        while True:
            print("New iteration of subscriptions loop")
            received = yield from self.stream.read()
            first_byte = received[0][0]
            self.parameter = received[0][-len(received[0])+1:].decode("utf-8")
            # Subscribe request
            if first_byte == 1:
                print("subscription request received for parameter "+self.parameter)
            # Unsubscribe request
            elif first_byte == 0:
                print("Unsubscription request received for parameter "+self.parameter)


    @asyncio.coroutine
    def publish(self):
        print("Entered publish coroutine")
        while True:
            if self.parameter:
                print("New iteration of publish loop")

                # Make HTTP request
                url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+self.parameter
                response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', url)
                assert response.status == 200
                content = yield from response.read()

                # Decode JSON string
                decoded_json = json.loads(content.decode())

                # Get parameter value
                value = decoded_json["main"]["temp"]

                # Publish fetched values to subscribers
                message = bytearray(self.parameter+":"+str(value),"utf-8")
                print(message)
                pack = [message]

                print("before write")
                yield from self.stream.write(pack)
                print("after write")

            yield from asyncio.sleep(10)

test = Publisher()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test.main())
```

**subscriber.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import zmq

class Subscriber:
    XSUB_CONNECT = 'tcp://localhost:10000'

    def __init__(self):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.XSUB)
        self.socket.connect(Subscriber.XSUB_CONNECT)

    def loop(self):
        print(self.socket.recv())
        self.socket.close()

    def subscribe(self, parameter):
        self.socket.send_string('\x01'+parameter)
        print("Subscribed to parameter "+parameter)

    def unsubscribe(self, parameter):
        self.socket.send_string('\x00'+parameter)
        print("Unsubscribed to parameter "+parameter)

test = Subscriber()
test.subscribe("London")
while True:
    print(test.socket.recv())
```

And here is the output :

**Subscriber side :**

```
$ python3 subscriber.py 
    Subscribed to parameter London
    b'London:288.15'
```

**Publisher side :**

```
$ python3 publisher.py 
    before wait
    Entered subscriptions coroutine
    New iteration of subscriptions loop
    Entered publish coroutine
    subscription request received for parameter London
    New iteration of subscriptions loop
    New iteration of publish loop
    bytearray(b'London:288.15')
    before write
```

And the program is stuck there.

As you can see, `"before write"` appears in the output and the message is sent, but `"after write"` doesn't appear. So, I figured that an exception was probably raised and caught somewhere in the `self.stream.write(pack)` call stack.

If I send a `KeyboardInterrupt` to the Publisher, here is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "publisher.py", line 73, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(test.main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 304, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 276, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1136, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/selectors.py", line 432, in select
    fd_event_list = self._epoll.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<publish() done, defined at publisher.py:43> exception=TypeError("'NoneType' object is not iterable",)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 236, in _step
    result = coro.send(value)
  File "publisher.py", line 66, in publish
    yield from self.stream.write(pack)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<subscriptions() running at publisher.py:32> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at /usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py:399]>
```

So I guess my problem actually is this error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`, but I have no clue what's causing it.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to `yield from` the call to `self.stream.write()`, but `stream.write` [isn't actually a coroutine](http://aiozmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/aiozmq/stream.html#ZmqStream.write). When you call `yield from` on an item, Python internally calls `iter(item)`. In this case, the call to `write()` is returning `None`, so Python is trying to do `iter(None)` - hence the exception you see.

To fix it, you should just call `write()` like a normal function. If you want to actually wait until the `write` is flushed and sent to the reader, use [`yield from stream.drain()`](http://aiozmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/aiozmq/stream.html#ZmqStream.drain) after you make the call to `write()`:

```
print("before write")
self.stream.write(pack)
yield from self.stream.drain()
print("after write")
```

Also, to make sure that exception in `publish` get raised without needing to Ctrl+C, use `asyncio.gather` instead of `asyncio.wait`:

```
    yield from asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

With `asyncio.gather`, any exception thrown by a task inside `tasks` will be re-raised.